# How do I date a pigeon?

Tags: reigns

One of my current tasks in Reigns is “The Boyfriend: Date a pigeon”.

I’m not sure how to accomplish this. I’ve only met two birds so far while playing, and neither one of them seems open to dating.

How do I date a pigeon in Reigns?

Comment: +1 - Love the title.. definitely make me peek at the whole question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to meet with the Witch in the game. She may ask you at some point if you want to learn White Magic. You have to say yes. She may then ask you:

> Pronounce the holy word “Zgando” in the Eastern fashion.

If she does, answer “Ahboep".

She may then ask you later if you want to find love, to which you have to answer yes. The pigeon then may appear somewhen in the following options. If you see him, swipe to the right to like the photo, and you will date the pigeon.